# Sticky Footer Bootstrap problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I'm struggling to get the organization correct for a sticky footer.  I'd like it to stay at the end of the page if the container above does not reach it.  It's a sticky footer, correct?  I've looked at examples and can't figure out where I've went wrong.

http://bootply.com/71311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/, it is easy to add to a site and has a demo file.

Comment: This worked as a sticky-footer and CSSstickyfoter.com didn't.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this one works better: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ than the one from Ryan Fait. Simple and clean!

Comment: I you didn't succeed with this one, it is probably because you did it wrong! I use it all the time! Don't like the div .push they add in the first. You should really try to understand why the second one didn't work!